# rasm2 giving different output each time for x64

Tags: radare2, x86-64

Disassembling is great but when trying to re-assemble to opcode it gives different results each time. Example:

```
C:\>rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 -d "48898D80FEFFFF"  
mov qword [rbp - 0x180], rcx  
C:\>rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 "mov qword [rbp - 0x180], rcx"  
49898d80feffff
```

See the difference? The first byte has been changed and it keep the same behavior each time. Another issue is, I couldn't get it to assemble this instruction with 8 bytes it only gives me 4 bytes:

```
C:\>rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 -d "C7458C0000803F"  
mov dword [rbp - 0x74], 0x3f800000  
C:\>rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 "mov dword [rbp - 0x74], 0x3f800000"  
41c67400
```

But when I remove the the bits flag and set the registers to 32 bit it gives me the correct opcodes!

```
C:\>rasm2 -a x86 "mov dword [ebp - 0x74], 0x3f800000"  
c7458c0000803f
```

Why is it doing this and what did I do wrong?

[GitHub issue link](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/9933) for future reference.

Comment: `rasm2 -v` gives what? are you using the latest version?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik `rasm2 2.6.0-git 1 @ windows-x86-64 git.` I'm pretty sure it's the latest version.

Comment: I'm running the first two commands and have the same output (on Ubuntu though). I'll check windows later

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Any luck figuring it out? Also is there any alternative command line assembler/disassembler to rasm2? GUI versions are welcomed as well. My only purpose is to easily assemble/disassemble my subroutines on the fly without all the hustle that other apps is making.

Comment: sorry, didn't have enough time, but I can see you've opened a issue on GitHub - I would probably do the same.

Comment: I've asked core developers -- it's known issue. Probably will be resolved soon.

Comment: please add a link to the issue so others know it’s a bug. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Done.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug, and the issue that was opened by OP is now fixed on radare2 [Master](https://github.com/radare/radare2) and on the latest [releases](https://github.com/radare/radare2/releases).

```
$ rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 -d "48898D80FEFFFF"
mov qword [rbp - 0x180], rcx
$ rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 "mov qword [rbp - 0x180], rcx"
48898d80feffff

$ rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 -d "C7458C0000803F"
mov dword [rbp - 0x74], 0x3f800000
$ rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 "mov dword [rbp - 0x74], 0x3f800000"
c7458c0000803f
```

The fix can be found in this [link](https://github.com/radare/radare2/pull/10177).