# radare2 wrong output

Tags: radare2

I saw [rasm2 giving different output each time for x64](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18024/rasm2-giving-different-output-each-time-for-x64)
Take a look at this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 -d "41f6c7FF"
test r15b, 0xff

C:\WINDOWS\system32>rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 "test r15b, 0xff"
f7ffff000000

C:\WINDOWS\system32>rasm2 -v
rasm2 3.5.1 1 @ windows-x86-64 git.3.5.1
commit: 4ec482ba2d4f554beeafb3aa47758e970bcab937 build: Wed 05/15/2019__ 7:58:44.85
```

Is this some unresolved bug or did I do something wrong?

Comment: it's probably is a bug. I would ask for this in the r2's telegram group or file na issue on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, this is more likely a bug, feel free to submit it to radare2's [issue tracker](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues). In fact, GitHub is using also Markdown, so just copy/paste your question to the issue tracker, this should be enough.